# Обновление данных в UI в Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Есть таблица с данными в UI, которую могут редактировать несколько пользователей. Как обновлять таблицу для всех пользователей при изменении данных? Т.е. отправлять событие с сервера на обновление таблицы. Есть где-то подобные примеры? Нужно ли использовать AJAX/JavaScript или хватит thymeleaf?

Контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class BalanceRecordController {

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ErrorController.class);

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private BalanceService balanceService;


@RequestMapping(value = {"/home", "/login", "/"})
public String index(Map<String, Object> map) {
    map.put("balanceRecord", new BalanceRecord());
    map.put("balanceRecordList", balanceService.balanceRecordList(userService.getCurrentUser()));

    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBalanceRecord(@ModelAttribute("balanceRecord") BalanceRecord balanceRecord, BindingResult result) {
    balanceRecord.setUser(userService.getCurrentUser());
    balanceService.addBalanceRecord(balanceRecord);
    logger.info("BalanceRecord #".join(balanceRecord.getId().toString()).join(" was created"));
    return "redirect:/";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{balanceRecordId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteBalanceRecord(@PathVariable("balanceRecordId") Long balanceRecordId) {
    balanceService.removeBalanceRecord(balanceRecordId);
    logger.info("Balance record #".join(balanceRecordId.toString()).join(" was deleted"));
    return "redirect:/";
}
}
```

UI Thymeleaf

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <if th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(balanceRecordList)}">
                            <tr th:each="balanceRecord : ${balanceRecordList}">
                                <td type="text" th:text="${balanceRecord.date != null} ? ${#calendars.format(balanceRecord.date, 'dd.MM.yyyy')} : null"></td>
                                <td th:text="${balanceRecord.category}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${balanceRecord.title}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${balanceRecord.sign}"></td>
                                <td type="number" th:text="${balanceRecord.value}"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/delete/__${balanceRecord.id}__}">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" value="Delete"/>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </if>
                        <tr>
                            <form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${balanceRecord}" class="form-vertical">
                                <td><input type="date" th:field="*{date}" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{category}" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select th:field="*{sign}">
                                        <option value="COST">COST</option>
                                        <option value="INCOME">INCOME</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="number" th:field="*{value}" /></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" value="Add balance record" class="btn"/></td>
                            </form>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: WebSockets/long polling?

Comment: Вроде технология stomp называется